# Setting multiple toggleable KML layers on GoogleMaps with custom icons

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I would like to create a Google map with toggleable KML layers - every layer has its set of icons. Example of a map I would like to use can be seen [here](https://www.google.com/maps/d/viewer?mid=1AQ5Is7NjBGjPZpLji5fbApYnegk&ll=45.812053384127196%2C15.972973238805025&z=15).

I am unable to set separate layers on the map so I can continue with making them toggleable one by one.

These are my steps for obtaining data for KML layers on Google map:

```
1. Select "Download KML" 
2. I chose a layer ("Food stores" for example)
- I checked "Keep data up to date with network link KML" (Map will be maintained on Google maps and data should automatically refresh in my map on the website).
- I left unchecked "Export to a KML file" (because of the icons support)
```

Then I unzip downloaded files. Inside small code there is `<href>http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=16i6f7Jvm754_jzkltP-Ks_2pKbU&amp;lid=M97Oy53L0t4</href>` which I include in url of `sitesLayer` when passing data for function `loadKml()` at the bottom of the following code.

The problem with this is that I instantly get all those icons on the map, even if I have downloaded and included only 1 layer - the map shows all 4 of them. 
Am I missing something, in the code or in the steps for downloading KML files for separating layers/icons?

```
function initialize() {

    // Map settings
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(0,0);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: myLatlng
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);


    // Creating KML layers
    loadKml = function(opts,map){

        var layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer();
        opts.preserveViewport = true;
        if(map) {
            opts.map = map;
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(layer,'defaultviewport_changed',function() {
            var map=this.getMap(),
            bounds=map.get('kmlBounds') || this.getDefaultViewport();

            bounds.union(this.getDefaultViewport());
            map.set('kmlBounds',bounds);
            map.fitBounds(bounds); 
        });

        layer.setOptions(opts);
        return layer; 

    }

    // Setting KML layers
    var sitesLayer = loadKml({
        url: 'http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=1AQ5Is7NjBGjPZpLji5fbApYnegk&amp;lid=z-AEWAAfH9c',
        map: map
    });

    var sitesLayer2 = loadKml({
        url: 'http://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=16i6f7Jvm754_jzkltP-Ks_2pKbU&amp;lid=jY6tGqHtk80',
        map: map
    });

}


google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You need to get the icons into separate KML files.  That looks like it isn't the case right now.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?